# Cannot Read Property 'launchImageLibrary' of null - React-Native

Tags: react-native, imagepicker

I am using Image-Picker but it's giving me this error, here is my code.

I installed image-picker like this:

```
npm i react-native-image-picker
```

Code:

```
import {launchCamera,launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';
const openImageLibrary = () => {
    const options = {
        noData: true,
    };
        
    try{
        const result = launchImageLibrary(options)
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to access the launchImageLibrary method before the component has mounted. Make sure that you are calling the openImageLibrary function after the component has mounted.

To call the openImageLibrary function after the component has mounted, you can use the useEffect hook in your functional component.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker';

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
      noData: true,
    };
    try {
      const result = launchImageLibrary(options);
      console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    // Your component's JSX code here
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Still same issue